# why php and html mixed code is not working?

Tags: php, html

I tried to write this simple code but it's not working.
This is my code...

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <?php
    $color = "red";
    ?>

    <p>Roses are <?=$color?></p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

i saved this code as new.php
it shows in the browser window only "Roses are" text. the value of $color is not printed.
i also saved it as new.html but the result is same.
what is the problem? what have i done wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure that short tags are enabled on your server?

Comment: i'm not sure , how can i check that?

Comment: do a 'view source' in you browser. if the php code shows up there, you server is misconfigured and isn't running .php files through the php interpreter. by default, .html files are usually NOT run through php, so no surprise that's not working.

Comment: @palatok - If you don't know, then they probably aren't (unless you're running PHP 5.4).

Comment: @palatok are you running this on a server or your local machine? if it's on your local machine, are you running apache and navigating to the page, or double clicking the file to open it? your code works properly for me

Comment: i'm running on my local machine (double click to open)

Comment: double click to open won't run php, that's the issue then. you need an apache server (like xampp) and you need to navigate to it like localhost/somefolder/new.php double clicking it won't run the script. if you install xampp and start up the apache server, then stick your file inside the htdocs folder and use localhost/new.php, that should work

Comment: palatok: [Here](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) you can install XAMPP

@JeffHawthorne Just goto ask, are you a Community fan Jeff Hawthorne?

Comment: yes.. if i open it from apache then it's ok. but why does this happen? i've spent so much time for this stupid thing :(

Comment: it's because things like php and jsp have to be "run" not just opened

Comment: @Oskwish - i've not watched it, why?

Comment: @JeffHawthorne Characters are named Jeff Winger and Pierce Hawthorne, among others.

Comment: hah yeah i just IMDBed it. good stuff! no this is my name haha

Comment: PHP is a server-side language; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_language. This means that it must be run through a web server. JavaScript and HTML, on the other hand, are client-side - all interpretation is done by the browser. If you just double-click a php file, it isn't actually running through the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$color = "red";
?>

<?php echo('<p>Roses are '.$color.'</p>'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

or

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$color = "red";
?>

<p>Roses are <?php echo $color; ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <p>Roses are <?php echo $color; ?></p>  . i tried this also ... not working

Answer (score 2):

It seems like short tags are disabled on your server. Use this instead:

```
<?php $color = "red"; ?>

<p>Roses are <?php echo $color; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<?=$color?>` only works if you have short tags enabled in the configuration, or if you are using PHP 5.4 or higher.

Since it's not showing anything, this is clearly not the case. Either change the configuration, upgrade to PHP 5.4, or use the full `<?php echo $color ?>`